# R Apply Complete-function after condition has been met (per group)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have monthly values for a factor variable `Alphabet` (containing factorlevels X, Y and Z) for 2021. See tibble `DF` below.

Some observations only start occuring later in the year. For example, recordings of X only start in june 2021.

My problem is that the source of the data omits values if they are zero. So for example I have values for Y in January (Sum is 2), but the data on for February is omitted by the source since there are no values recorded. Then March Y has a `Sum` of 5 so it's back.

What I want to do is complete this dataset. So for Y, I want a row that says *feb 2021, Y, 0*. I tried using the `complete` function for this.

```
complete(Month2, nesting (Alphabet), fill =  list( Sum=0))
```

However, this also completes the values for X for the whole year, which is incorrect. X only exists since june 2021. See tibble `DF_Overcomplete` below.

My solution is to have complete function conditional per factor level. So only after it has encountered a `Sum` that is not zero, it should start to complete and populate the `Month2`, `Alphabat`, and `Sum` variables. For Y it can complete the whole year (since January has a Sum !=0), but for X I only want to apply the complete function from June.

DF:

```
  structure(list(Month2 = structure(c(6L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("jan 2021", 
    "feb 2021", "mrt 2021", "apr 2021", "mei 2021", "jun 2021", "jul 2021", 
    "aug 2021", "sep 2021", "okt 2021"), class = "factor"), Alphabet = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Sum = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 24L, 46L, 71L, 91L, 
    97L, 54L, 57L, 81L)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

DF_Overcomplete:

```
structure(list(Month2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("jan 2021", "feb 2021", 
"mrt 2021", "apr 2021", "mei 2021", "jun 2021", "jul 2021", "aug 2021", 
"sep 2021", "okt 2021"), class = "factor"), Alphabet = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("X", 
"Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Sum = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 9, 24, 46, 71, 91, 97, 
54, 57, 81)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

So basically I want this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the start dates for each Alphabet, you should just filter at the end.  Otherwise how could you tell if X starts in May but there just weren't any observations?

Comment: That's an assumption I have to make/risk I am willing to take. The month with the first observation is the month the Alphabet level started. 

In my full dataset Alphabet consists of 68 levels.  Then I have to manually look up the start dates for each and filter for each at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the factor Month2 to a Date so it's easily ordered.
Then calculate the min and max month for each Alphabet.
Use the complete as before, join and filter by the min and max.

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
df <- df %>% mutate(yr_mo = as.Date(paste('01', Month2), format = '%d %b %Y'))
start_end <- df %>% group_by(Alphabet) %>% summarise(min(yr_mo), max(yr_mo))
df_complete <- df %>% 
  complete(Month2, nesting(Alphabet), fill =  list(Sum = 0L)) %>% 
  mutate(yr_mo = as.Date(paste('01', Month2), format = '%d %b %Y')) %>% 
  left_join(start_end) %>% 
  filter(yr_mo >= `min(yr_mo)`, yr_mo <= `max(yr_mo)`) %>% 
  select(-c(`min(yr_mo)`, `max(yr_mo)`, yr_mo))

df_complete %>% print(n = Inf)
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   Month2   Alphabet   Sum
   <fct>    <fct>    <int>
 1 jan 2021 Y            2
 2 jan 2021 Z            2
 3 feb 2021 Y            0
 4 feb 2021 Z            9
 5 mrt 2021 Y            5
 6 mrt 2021 Z           24
 7 apr 2021 Y            0
 8 apr 2021 Z           46
 9 mei 2021 Y            0
10 mei 2021 Z           71
11 jun 2021 X            1
12 jun 2021 Y           10
13 jun 2021 Z           91
14 jul 2021 X            1
15 jul 2021 Y            0
16 jul 2021 Z           97
17 aug 2021 X            0
18 aug 2021 Y            4
19 aug 2021 Z           54
20 sep 2021 X            2
21 sep 2021 Y            2
22 sep 2021 Z           57
23 okt 2021 Y            2
24 okt 2021 Z           81
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great solution. One minor tweak: grouping and then taking the min and max per group has one drawback. If the Alphabet-value is 0 in Oktober, it won't show up in the data, which means the max value is taken as September, As seen also in your example, X is missing in Oktober. Instead of using the max of the yr_mo variable, I made a seperate max_yr_mo <- as.Date("2021-10-01") to filter by. But it works great. One thing, could you maybe explain why you you use backticks here in the code?

Comment: I could have avoided the backticks by assigning legal names in the summarise step.  As it is, the default name assignment includes parentheses, so won't work as an object name without the backticks.